# getAllConnections is not a functoin

Tags: angular, jsplumb

jsPlumb2.x had getAllConnections on instance to get all the connected uuids. I'm using 5.x version and getting this error and could not find any alternate function in source code as well as documentation

```
ERROR TypeError: this.instance.getAllConnections is not a function
```

Which function can be used alternatively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAllConnections` was a method used to get every connection the instance was managing:

```
// get all connections managed by the instance of jsplumb.
this.getAllConnections = function () {
  return connections;
};
```

in 5.x you can just access the array directly on the instance:

```
readonly connections:Array<Connection> = []
```